# <h:form action="#{bean.method()}"> gets called twice

Tags: forms, jsf

I am writing a Java EE application for changing password. For taking old and new password inputs I am using a jsf form.

```
 <h:form method="post" action="#{changePass.updatePassword()}" >
     <h:inputText id="username" value = "#{changePass.username}" readonly="true" required="true"/>
     <h:inputSecret id="oldPassword" value = "#{changePass.oldPassword}" required="true" />
     <h:inputSecret id="newPassword" value = "#{changePass.newPassword}" required="true" />
     <h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" value = "#{changePass.confirmPassword}" required="true" />
     <button id="update" type="submit"></button>
 </h:form>
```

My intention is to call updatePassword() function in changePass bean class when user clicks on the button. But this fuction gets called twice in this form.

1. when the form loads
2. When the user clocks on the button

How can I avoid this calling during the form load?

Comment: Can you post the bean ? And can you remove all attributes in the form tag please  ? Does it work, check my other comment as well. No tag in post and  put a real button with the action in it.

Comment: Also <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{changePass.updatePassword()" />

Comment: If that helps, Accept as answer and upvote. Low reputation members rarely upvote me. :(.

Comment: Where did you learn JSF? You seem to never have seen/tried a simple Hello World example like one shown in our wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xhtml should look like this:

```
     <h:form>
        <h:inputSecret id="newPassword" value = "#{changePass.newPassword}" required="true" />


         <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{changePass.updatePassword}" />
     </h:form>
```

If that still doesn't work then there is smtg wrong with your bean. Also you might want to follow some tutorials. I'm not entirely sure the syntax you used is wrong but it's the first time I've seen it though.